# How to fix output?

Tags: c++

So basically all this program does is read in the data into the array of structs of student_type and all the print_students functions does is output the data i get mostly the correct output but i also get random huge numbers.The file data contains the following info and my code is below how do i fix my output?

```
Smith
John
123456
3.4
J
1750.4
302
Fairmont St NW
Washington
DC
20059
Smitty
Frank
78910
2.7
F
1940.7
302
Sixth St SW
Washington
DC
20059
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct Address_type

{
    int street_no;
    string street_name;
    string city;
    string state;
    int zip;
};
struct student_type
{
    string lname;
    string fname;
    int ID;
    float GPA;
    char classification;
    float account_balance;
    Address_type student_address;
};
void print_students(student_type[]); // prototypein
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    student_type students[5];
    myfile.open("infile.txt");
    string name1, name2, name3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        myfile >> students[i].lname;
        myfile >> students[i].fname;
        myfile >> students[i].ID;
        myfile >> students[i].GPA;
        myfile >> students[i].classification;
        myfile >> students[i].account_balance;
        myfile >> students[i].student_address.street_no;
        myfile >> name1 >> name2 >> name3;
        students[i].student_address.street_name = name1 + " " + name2 + " " + name3;
        myfile >> students[i].student_address.city;
        myfile >> students[i].student_address.state;
        myfile >> students[i].student_address.zip;
        print_students(students);
    }
    myfile.close();
}
void print_students(student_type students[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << students[i].lname << endl;;
        cout<< students[i].fname<<endl;
        cout<< students[i].ID<<endl;
        cout<< students[i].GPA<<endl;
        cout<< students[i].classification<<endl;
        cout<< students[i].account_balance<<endl;
        cout<< students[i].student_address.street_no<<endl;
        cout<<students[i].student_address.street_name<<endl;
        cout << students[i].student_address.city << endl;
        cout << students[i].student_address.state << endl;
        cout << students[i].student_address.zip << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Random huge numbers" usually means "uninitialized data" which usually means "initialize your values properly before using them".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're printing all of your student data on the first iteration of the loop. You should hold off until you've loaded all your data.

Additionally, in C++ it's important to use the Standard Library containers and do your best to avoid C-style fixed-length arrays in situations like this where you're reading in from a file of unknown length.

That is use this:

```
std::vector<student_type> students;
```

This can be added to with things like `push_back` on a properly composed `student_type` record.

Then you can pass that through by reference to any function that needs it, like `print_students` for example. Right now, for whatever reason, you just *assume* that there will be three entries in that array (of length five?) and go ahead and dump it out even if it wasn't populated.